# Is Masm can't compile psrldq directive?

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32

The codes have only one line, I guess if I miss some declares. My ml's version is `6.14.8444`.

The error is:

> error A2008: syntax error : xmm

The assembly code:

```
.686
.XMM
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

.code
   psrldq  xmm0, 1
end
```

And I tried inline assembly in vs2013. It is OK. The code:

```
int _tmain(unsigned int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    __asm {
        psrldq  xmm0, 1
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`psrldq` is part of [SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2) which was introduced in 2001. MASM version 6.14.8444 was released 1999 (http://bytepointer.com/masm/index.htm#MASM_6.14). Therefore, SSE2 is unknown in that MASM version.

If your CPU supports SSE2 you can insert data that represent the opcode:

```
.686
.XMM
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

.code
    db 66h, 0Fh, 73h, 0D8h, 01h      ; psrldq  xmm0, 1
end
```

Comment: Isn't there a modern version of MASM?  And BTW, in case this isn't obvious to future readers, manually encoding all the SIMD instructions in a function you're writing basically defeats the purpose of using an assembler.  It's not maintainable, so it's not a particularly useful solution.  Use a newer assembler.

Comment: @Mysticial: I forget the details, but MASM 6.14 was the last version that (something), which is why it's still in use.  Maybe something about 16-bit code, or running under DOS, or some output format support thing?  Or a distribution / license issue?

Comment: @PeterCordes: MASM version 6.14.8444 is shipped with the [MASM32 package](http://www.masm32.com/). Later versions of MASM support SSE2 but I remember that you cannot just exchange the `ML.EXE`.

Comment: The reason MASM32 ships with 6.14 (and not 6.15) is because as of 6.15 the EULA required you to have a VC++ 6.0 license while 6.14 did not. 6.15 ended up being the last version capable of creating 16-bit applications. The last version where the tools ran under DOS was 6.11 while later versions switched to PE console executable format.

Comment: thanks for your answer. It is a special way. I try your way, it worked. And I try to use ML.exe with vs2013 to compile, it seems also worked.